# Constant update with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple `Flask` program as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    import datetime
    lines = """ 
    This is the index page
    <br>
    %s
    """%( datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") )
    return lines
```

But I would like the date to continue to update every second (without having to refresh the page). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: without having to refresh the page manually yourself?...or without the browser reloading the entire page when refreshing?

Comment: Without having to reload the page manually. As in, you sit and watch and the date just changes.

Comment: Keyword to lookup: Websockets